# TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable openerp

Tags: python, copy

when i want to execute my dopy_data, to get object value and incriment it, and duplicate the object i get this error : TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable

```
class immo_assurance(osv.osv):
    _name = "immo.assurance"
    _description = "Assurance"

    def copy_data(self, cr, uid, id, default=None, context=None):
        if default is None:
        default = {}

        res = 1

        idea = self.browse(cr, uid, id)

        res += int(idea.nContrat)

        #res = default.get('nContrat')

        default['nContrat'] = res

        return super(immo_assurance, self).copy_data(
            cr, uid, id, default=res, context=context)

    _columns = {
                'name':fields.char('Code',size=10,required=True),
                'nContrat':fields.integer('Ndu    contrat',size=60,required=True),
                'dDebut':fields.date('Début'),
                'dFin':fields.date('Fin'),
                'id_societe' : fields.many2one('immo.societe'     ,'Société',required=True),
                'cAnnuel':fields.float('Cout annuel',size=60),              
                'commentaire':fields.char('Commentaires',size=10),
                'articles':fields.one2many('immo.article','assurance','Liste Articles',               readonly=True),
                }           

immo_assurance()
```

`

Comment: Could you please review the code you have posted, making sure it matches the indentation etc. in the code you are running, and provide the full error traceback.

Comment: Also, this question seems to be a less-informative version of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23118239/how-to-get-value-from-object-with-copy-data-function-and-incriment-it-and-dupli) you created earlier. You should edit and improve your questions rather than opening new ones.

Comment: i edit the question, this my class code

Comment: @user3542605 There are still indentation problems with your code. Look at the question text body, it clearly isn't correct.

Comment: @user3542605 I have attempted to fix your indentation errors, but it is difficult to be sure I've gotten it right. Please review this to make sure that it now matches your code (remembering that indentation level is meaningful in Python).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

default is a dictionary you can't  return this:

```
  super(immo_assurance, self).copy_data(cr, uid, id, **default=res**, context=context)`
```

*default=res** this is incorrect

but

```
 def copy_data(self, cr, uid, id, default=None, context=None):
    if default is None:
       default = {}
    res = 1
    idea = self.browse(cr, uid, id)
    res += int(idea.nContrat)
    default['nContrat'] = res
    return super(immo_assurance, self).copy_data(
       cr, uid, id, default, context)
```